# want to pass data from parent to child component in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The code which is given below returns an error. I don't understand what's going wrong. Can anyone help me with the solution?

Here's a screenshot of the code
[image]

And the error is...
[image: Error message]

Comment: Please share the code itself instead of images. Just paste your code and use `code` formatting.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error because right after `return`, you don't return or start to return anything. Use parentheses when you want to return multiple JSX lines in your render method.
Instead of:

```
return
    <div>
        <span>Something</span>
    </div>
```

Use:

```
return (
    <div>
        <span>Something</span>
    </div>
);
```

or start with a JSX part right after your `return`:

```
return <div>
          <span>Foo</span>
      </div>;
```

Answer (score 0):

In React, it is recomended to use parenthesis around your HTML, while returning it as a JSX element.

Update your `render` block as below...

```
return (
    <div>
        <span>Something</span>
    </div>
);
```